# How to filter an item using one of its child set in nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have an object that looks like the following ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping namespace="test" assembly="test" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">

<class name="Person" table="`Person`">
        <id name="ItemId" access="property" column="`ItemId`">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="Name" column="`A`" />
        <property name="Age" column="`B`" />
        <set name="Email" inverse="true">
            <key column="`Name`" />
            <one-to-many class="EmailClass" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I would like to do a nHibernate query to filter these records by their email addresses

I've tried something along these lines ..

```
var childCriteria = QueryOver.Of<EmailClass>().Where(c => c.EmailAddress.ToString().IsLike("%" + strSearch + "%")).Select(c => c.EmailID);

var query = session.QueryOver<Person>().WithSubquery.WhereExists(childCriteria).Future();
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong. The question is, is it possible to search through the child set of a data object? or is it better deal for me to just searching the child table directly then find its parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, I'd say.

I. some notes to mapping first...

Firstly, I assume that the `EmailClass` has relation to `Person` as well *(because on DB level this is bidirectional relation)*.

```
public class EmailClass 
{
    ...
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; } // inverse mapping
}
```

That would be logical, because this DB relation is existing anyhow. It is already expressed as a Person's `<set>` named `Email`.  And should be also must, because we used **`inverse="true"`**, which expect bidirectional mapping...

Which also makes me to dispute the mapping. Are you sure, that this mapping is correct:

```
<class name="Person" ...
    // KEY column of this entity is ItemId (seems to be int)
    <id name="ItemId" column="`ItemId`" ...
    ...
    <set name="Email" inverse="true">
        // this mapping says: NHibernate, try to find the value
        // of the ItemId in the Person table
        // in the column Name of the table EmailClass ... ?
        <key column="`Name`" />
        ...
        // would expect
        <key column="ItemId" /> // column inside of EmailClass table
```

I am trying to say, usually, we can see, that the `<id>` column name used as a Key of a root entity *(Person)* is the same as `the <key>` column used for collection mapping.

So, I'd expect that `EmailClass` table should contain *column* like `"ItemId"` or `"Person_ID"` which would keep the reference to the `Person` table.

II. subquery filtering

Let's now continue with the query, expecting the above is true.

```
// An Alias, to be used later
Person person = null;

var childCriteria = QueryOver
    .Of<EmailClass>()
    // more QueryOver native style of a LIKE expression
    .WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.EmailAddress).IsLike(strSearch, MatchMode.Anywhere)
    // trick here
    // if we want to use the EXISTS later
    // we need to join outer and inner query here
    // and that's a place for outer query ALIAS
    .Where(c => c.PersonId == person.ItemId)
    .Select(c => c.PersonId); // must select something...

var query = session
    // ALIAS expressing the outer query in action again
    .QueryOver<Person>(() => person)
    .WithSubquery
    .WhereExists(childCriteria)
    .Future();
```

So, as we can see, almost there... Just a bit *QueryOver-ish* style for LIKE, and the essential WHERE clause Person = EmailAddress.Person

III. mapping ... suggestion

Let me, please, also provide some draft of the mapping I'd expect/suggest:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int ItemId { get; set;}
    public virtual IList<EmailClass> Emails { get; set; } // plural Emails
}
public class EmailClass 
{
    ...
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; } // inverse mapping
}
```

mapping:

```
<class name="Person" ...
    ...
    <set name="Emails"        // plural
      cascade="all-delete-orphan" // usually makes sense to rely on NHibernate cascade
      batch-size="25"         // great feature improving 1 + N issue
      inverse="true"  >       // already used, improves WRITE operations sequence
      <key column="ItemId" /> // ItemId should column in the EmailClass table
        <one-to-many class="EmailClass" />
    </set>
</class>
<class name="EmailClass">
   <id ... 
   <many-to-one name="Person" column="ItemId" /> // the same column as in above <set
   ...
```

Comment: 1) Yes, the email class does have the person id pointing it back to the person object. 3) Yes, that looks like what i have

Comment: That's good, I'd say. So, your query *(with few adjustments showed in the answer)* should be working. Or? The point of querying collection is: use subqueries. With JOIN, your resultset could be returning root entity multiple times. That will lead to unexpected results when paging...

Comment: Ok - run into a problem ... my Email class does not have a person id, it has a person class instead .. will the query still work?

Comment: Indeed your solutions works as well and it looks like it's pulling a unique set at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
session.QueryOver<Person>()
    .JoinQueryOver(p => p.EmailClass)
    .Where(e => e.EmailAddress.IsLike(strSearch, MatchMode.Anywhere))
    .Future<Person>();
```

This assumes `EmailClass.EmailAddress` is a `string`.

This will generate SQL that looks like this:

```sql
select
    Person.* /* all person fields */
from
    Person
    inner join EmailClass on EmailClass.Name = Person.Name
where
    EmailClass.EmailAddress like '%strSearch%' /* your search term */
```

Comment: Yes - that's the inner join SQL that i'm looking for.

Comment: It's not giving me the option to choose an attribute to filter for at the "where" level ... where (e => e.EmailAddress ..) is not selectable ... any thoughts?

Comment: @aggietech: Does a person have many email addresses? If so, you might have to explicitly specify the type parameter for `.JoinQueryOver`: `.JoinQueryOver<EmailClass>(p => p.EmailClass)`

Comment: Yes - one person can have a list of email addresses